# Reading a file with a skip (or delition) of a certain section of text from a txt.file

Tags: java, string, file, text, hashmap

I just recently started to study Java and faced with such a problem.

How can I read a .txt file and skip or delete a specific piece of text?
In my case, the section to be deleted always looks like this:
1) Begin with string: ======= (80 equals "=" characters without spaces)
2) End with the same string: ======= (80 equals "=" characters without spaces)
3) Between these lines contains meta-information, which I need to delete or skip while reading, along with the lines of the beginning and end of this section

For example:
file.txt contains:

```
================================================================================
<some strings with text here>
================================================================================
abcd
asdfd
sdfgdfdf
```

I need to get only strings:

```
abcd
asdfd
sdfgdfdf
```

The maximum Java version to run is 8.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What did you try yourself? Anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file line by line and everytime you encounter this special line, start skipping until you encounter it again.

For example: (`in` is your input stream)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
boolean skip = false;
while((String line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.equals("") {
        skip = !skip;
    }
    else if(!skip) {
        sb.append(line).append("\r\n");
    }
}
String fileContents = sb.toString();
```

Comment: @JoopEggen hoho <3 thanks

Comment: @JoopEggen I should probably delete the whole question

Comment: No, no, it is the right approach. It keeps a state (`skip`), so a Stream solution is not appropriate. Maybe with `line.startsWith("==============")`

Comment: @JoopEggen I know, I meant the whole question because it is sort of `What did he even try` or `does he even know java` :p

Comment: Okay, evidently the OP is a beginner. But there is some willingness to program. Not quite ready for StackOverflow